# Django 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an encoded id field based on the default User object's id, but receive the following error (full trace):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/pumac3/registration/models.py", line 52, in <module>
    class Coach(models.Model):
  File "/Users/default_user/Documents/pumac3/pumac3/registration/models.py", line 61, in Coach
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)))
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My Coach model in my `models.py` looks as follows:

```
class Coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

    # Sets default user values
    user.is_active = False

    # For account activation and password resetting
    user_timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=int(time.time()))
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.id)))
    user_token = models.CharField(max_length=254, default=default_token_generator.make_token(user))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Coaches"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Returns the name of the coach if has name, otherwise returns email."""
        if self.name:
            return self.name
        else:
            return self.user.email

    def update_token(self):
        """Updates the user_token and timestamp for password reset or invalid activation"""
        self.user_timestamp = int(time.time())
        self.user_token = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
        self.save()

    @staticmethod
    def is_coach(user):
        return hasattr(user, 'coach')

    @staticmethod
    def authorized(user):
        """Returns a queryset of Coach objects the user can view and modify."""
        if hasattr(user, 'coach'):
            # check that the user is a coach
            return user.coach

    @staticmethod
    def authorized_organizations(user):
        """
        Returns a queryset of organizations the user can view and modify.
        """
        if hasattr(user, 'coach'):
            return user.coach.organizations.all()
```

I've tried looking at other problems similar to mine, but were that the person specified a primary key, so no default `id` field was created by Django. However, I'm not doing this in my `Coach` model, and even if so, shouldn't the Django default User model contain an `id` property?

I suspect that the problem is that the `id` field only exists after an instance of `User` is actually created, so I cannot create the value for `user_id`. Should I look to instead instantiate this value outside of `models.py`, after I create an instance of the `User` class?

Comment: Django's `OneToOneField` is meant for models where there is a unique and one-to-one mapping to the parent table. So, the parent_id (in your case, `user_id`) is the default primary key of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the instance data in the top level code of your class.
At the point the code is run (import time) there is simply no instance yet.
If you want to initialize an instance with calculated data, overwrite the `__init__` method of the class.